# Fast way to substitute string pairs in file

Tags: python, perl, sed, substitution

I have a file with ~10,000 lines containing 2 columns:

```
org_string1 \t replacement_string1
org_string2 \t replacement_string2
```

What is the best way (speed/convenience) to substitute all these org_string with their corresponding replacement_string in another text file (doing 10k replacement in a second file)?

I am planning to convert them to a sed substitution command but not sure about the speed performance and whether it will exceed the max command line limit in linux.

Assumption:

1. All org_string and replacement_string are unique.
2. The org_string is a single word (surrounded by space) in the input file.

Comment: So you want to make 10k different replacements in a second file? From my experience `sed` will get very slow, even if you give it a file with 10k `s/org_string1/replacement_string1/` lines. I did not try Perl or Python with a 10k dicitonary of regular expressions and substitutions.

Comment: my guess it won't be problem to convert/replace in perl since perl will do this in milliseconds.

Comment: The single replacement will be fast. But checking each line against 10k patterns will sum up.

Comment: Replace text quickly in very large file [StackExchange] http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/255373/replace-text-quickly-in-very-large-file

Comment: @ssr1012 The question you link to is not about doing 10k different replacement on possibly every line of a file. The large number of replacements is the problem here.

Comment: @FullName Your dictionary need not contain regular expressions, simple strings will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a technique using Perl which may help:

```
my %map = (
    'the'   => 'a',
    'fox'   => 'frog',
    'jumps' => 'somersaults'
);

my $line = "the quick bown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

$line =~ s{\b(\w+)\b}{$map{$1} // $1}eg;

say $line;
```

This example uses a hard-coded hash mapping orig_strings to replacement_strings - in your case you would populate this mapping hash by reading the file of mapping pairs.

Then the regular expression uses `\b(\w+)\b` to capture each word in the line and pass to the replacement side via `$1`.  Because the `/e` option is specified, the right-hand side of the substitution is treated as a Perl expression, and the result of evaluating the expression is the replacement text.  `$map{$1}` uses the original word as a key to the mapping hash to look up the replacement text.  The `// $1` part is saying if the hash lookup returns `undef` (i.e. there is no replacement for this word) then just use the original text.

The `\w+` part will match a string of word or digit or underscore characters.  You might want only alphabetic characters and perhaps apostrophes and hyphens.  To achieve this, use `[a-zA-Z'-]+` instead of `\w+`.

This should be very fast because there's only one regex run across each line and only one hash lookup for each word in each line.

Comment: This is way faster than doing multiple substitution. Thank you.